# Probability that the third-largest of 39 nine-sided dice will be equal to 8

Tags: probability, dice

How can I calculate the probability that the third-largest of 39 nine-sided dice will be equal to 8? How would this be done mathematically?

The following is possible for example:

(two nines, one eight, rest is below 8)

(three eights, rest is below 8)

(one nine, two eights, rest is below 8)

Comment: Do you accept if there aremore than one 8's, or do you want just one? E.g. $9,8,9$ and the rest is smaller

Comment: Just one 8 :-) Thank you for helping!

Comment: Well, I guess it's the same as saying that thirty six of the dice will have a value of $< 8$, one die has value 8, and two have a value $9$. In how many ways can this be done? Then divide that by the total number of cases.

Comment: @MattiP. You meant to say $2$ have value $>8$ not $\geq8$ since OP says only one $8$

Comment: I'm sorry. There CAN be more than one 8. I'm sorry for the confusion. I made my post a bit more clear

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I began formulatng this answer before the clarification that the OP wanted exactly one eight (i.e., two nines, one eight, all others at most seven). The below is about a too general case then.

---

This amounts to: At least three dice are $\ge 8$, but at most two dice are $>8$.

We count outcomes:

- No nine: $8^{39}$
- No nine and no eight: $7^{39}$
- No nine and one eight: $39\cdot 7^{38}$
- No nine and two eights: ${39\choose 2}\cdot 7^{37}$

Hence

> No nine and at least three eights: $8^{39}-7^{39}-39\cdot7^{38}-{39\choose 2}\cdot 7^{37}$

Use a similar method to count

> One nine and at least two eights: ...

and

> Two nines and at least one eight: ...

Finally, add these three counts of outcomes.

Comment: I'm sorry. There CAN be more than one 8. I'm sorry for the confusion. 
Also the rule "at most two dice are > 8" can be changed as there could be three eights, and then the third largest would be 8. If it makes sense! Otherwise thank you so you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$$\binom {39} 2 \cdot 37 \frac{7^{36}}{9^{39}}$$ 
choose 2 from 39 that have the value 9. That's $\binom{39}2$. Now choose one that holds 8, 37 dice left, hence 37. The rest can be anything from 1,..,7, hence $7^{36}$. Total number of cases is $9^{39}$.

Sorry for the typo, I'm typing from my phone.

Comment: I'm sorry. There CAN be more than one 8. I'm sorry for the confusion.